# Excel VBA using SUMPRODUCT and COUNTIFS - issue of speed

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue of speed. (Apologies for the long post…). I am using Excel 2013 and 2016 for Windows.

I have a workbook that performs 10,000+ calculations on a 200,000 cell table (1000 rows x 200 columns).

Each calculation returns an integer (e.g. count of filtered rows) or more usually a percentage (e.g. sum of value of filtered rows divided by sum of value of rows). The structure of the calculation is variations of the `SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS())` idea, along the lines of:

```
=IF($B6=0,
    0,
    SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(
    Data[CompanyName], 
    CompanyName,
    Data[CurrentYear], 
    TeamYear,
    INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(TeamYear&"R2",RealProgress,2,FALSE)),
    "<>"&"",
    Data[High Stage],
    NonDom[NonDom]
    ))
    /$B6
)
```

Explaining above:

1. the pair Data[Company Name] and CompanyName is the column in the table and the condition value for the first filter.
2. The pair Data[Current Year] and TeamYear are the same as above and constitute the second filter.
3. The third pair looks up a intermediary table and returns the name of the column, the condition (`"<>"&""`) is ‘not blank’, i.e. returns all rows that have a value in this column
4. Finally, the fourth pair is similar to 3 above but returns a set of values that matches the set of values in
5. Lastly, the four filters are joined together with AND statements.
   It is important to note that across all the calculations the same principle is applied of using `SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS())` – however there are many variations on this theme.
   At present, using Calculate on a select range of sheets (rather than the slower calculating the whole workbook), yields a speed of calculation of around 30-40 seconds. Not bad, and tolerable as calculations aren’t performed all the time.

Unfortunately, the model is to be extended and now could approach 20,000 rows rather 1,000 rows. Calculation performance is directly linked to the number of rows or cells, therefore I expect performance to plummet!

The obvious solution [1] is to use arrays, ideally passing an array, held in memory, to the formula in the cell and then processing it along with the filters and their conditions (the lookup filters being arrays too).

The alternative solution [2] is to write a UDF using arrays, but reading around the internet the opinion is that UDFs are much slower than native Excel functions.

Two questions:

1. Is solution [1] possible, and the best way of doing this, and if so how would I construct it?
2. If solution [1] is not possible or not the best way, does anyone have any thoughts on how much quicker solution [2] might be compared with my current solution?
3. Are there other better solutions out there? I know about Power BI Desktop, PowerPivot and PowerQuery – however this is a commercial application for use by non-Excel users and needs to be presented in the current Excel ‘grid’ form of rows and columns.

Thanks so much for reading!

Addendum: I'm going to try running an array calculation for each sheet on the Worksheet.Activate event and see if there's some time savings.

Comment: IMO this question is impossible to provide a good answer to. There are simply too many things that *might* help but it's impossible to say for sure without a lot more information and preferable a copy of the workbook. For example, pivot tables might be a good solution. Replacing your VLOOKUP with either the binary search version or INDEX and MATCH might help. UDFs can, in some cases, be faster than formulas if they allow you to short-circuit some processing. Converting the last condition into a TRUE/FALSE formula in your source data might help. As I said, too many options. ;)

Comment: Thanks Rory. I have tried INDEX MATCH rather than VLOOKUP but it was slower. I also tried the '2 VLOOKUPs' solution - but that didn't work either.
Pivots aren't an answer as I need close control and good formatting over the output.
I'll have a think about the TRUE/FALSE idea though...sounds interesting!
For anyone else, I am looking for general pointers and advice as I appreciate that specific solutions are going to be down to me!

Comment: Like I said, too many possibilities...There is rarely an absolute cure for performance issues. You might invest in FastExcel to determine exactly where the bottleneck is. (the INDIRECT obviously won't be helping matters)

Comment: I use the INDIRECT so that the formulae can be copied over a whole grid of hundreds on each sheet. Theoretically I could replace each formula but that would take a long time and if the formulae changes, then I would be changing thousands of formulae across the workbook. I'll have a look at FastExcel though! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Writing data to arrays is normally a good idea if looking to increase speed. Done like this:

```
Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant

'Set path for Table variable
  Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

'Create Array List from Table
  myArray = myTable.DataBodyRange
```

([Source](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables))